# Aggregate and compress CSS files on Responsive Site

Tags: drupal-7, responsive-design

What is the best practice for aggregating and compressing CSS files on a responsive site. When I select the Aggregate and Compress CSS files option in Drupal 7 under performance and look at the site on a mobile device it is using the style sheet from the main site not the specified one for that device. I am using [AdaptiveTheme](http://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme).

Comment: I think you are mixing two things. The aggregate and compress css files options just specifies if the css files will be aggregated and compressed. I think your problem is more related to your theme AdaptiveTheme settings

Answer (score 0):

Your site performance wouldn't be slow down. It is somewhere other things rather than CSS minification. [Online YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/) minifies properly and rather than slowed down your page load speed, it enhances page speed.

Answer (score 0):

Well according to the documentation

- You need to turn on Production mode
- Any additional changes you make you need to resave the theme (so that it can be rendered properly again)
- All responsive themes are placed into one complete file
- Also highly advisabled to install [AT Tools](http://drupal.org/project/at_tools) as it has additional features that help you out with regards to this

> Responsive Styles - Production mode
>
> When in production mode all the responsive stylesheets are aggregated into one file and use embedded @media queries. AT Core will automatically aggregate the CSS from each of the development mode stylesheets and wrap it in the right media query. This reduces the number of HTTP requests from 5 to 1.
>
> This file is always called: ThemeName.responsive.styles.css
>
> By default will find this file at: ~/[public files]/adaptivetheme/[ThemeName]/ThemeName.responsive.styles.css
>
> However you can choose where to save AT's generated files, for example you can save them directly to your theme or enter a custom directory path - see File Generation System.
>
> NOTE: please see the section below titled "Relative Paths in Responsive Styles".

Ref: [Referencing AdaptiveThemes documentation](http://adaptivethemes.com/documentation/css)